# How can i remove any allauth page?

Tags: django, django-allauth

I want to remove signup, reset password, and change password page from allauth django app.
what should i do? because I need only login page.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: and don't add pictures like that to your question.what does `enter image description here` mean?

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: see [*Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). [edit] the question and include code fragments.

Comment: That a screen shot of pages that I want to remove. But i don't know why when I post my questions it look like this.